# Compiler is skipping the return line. Binary Search by Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I have Made a Binary Search program using a recursive call (Ignore the printf statements). Upon running the program you will realise that it runs fine and gets the index of the element to be found but in :

```
else if (element == arr[mid])
    {
        printf("\n%d\nmid = %d\nstart = %d\nend = %d\n\n", i, mid,start,end);
        return mid;
    }
```

It does not return mid, it returns the 0 at the end instead. (I have tried values other than 0).

I have also tried to return mid at the end instead of returning 0. It always returns 4.

The entire code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[100]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, start=0, end=9, i=0;

int BinaryRecursivSearch(int element, int start, int end)
{
    int mid = (start + end)/2;

    i++;

    printf("\n%d\nmid = %d\nstart = %d\nend = %d\n\n", i, mid,start,end);

    if (mid == start)
    {
        if(element!=end)
        {
            printf("\nElement not found");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    else if (element < arr[mid])
        BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, mid);

    else if (element > arr[mid])
        BinaryRecursivSearch(element, mid, end);

    else if (element == arr[mid])
    {

//For the last iteration (or recursion) mid has the correct value in printf

printf("\n%d\nmid = %d\nstart = %d\nend = %d\n\n", i, mid,start,end);
        return mid;  //It skips this
    }

    return 0;  //It returns this value
}

int main()
{
    int element, index;

    printf("Enter the element to be searched for: ");
    scanf("%d", &element);

    index = BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, end);

    printf("\n Element found at %d position", index + 1 );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: _Compiler is skipping the return line_, you really should not blame the compiler, it's very very likely that it's your fault.

Comment: Note that your last code block starts with `else`, perhaps that is why it is skipped. I suggest you alter one of the two identical `printf` messages, so you know which one is being printed.

Comment: You need to `return BinaryRecursivSearch();` when recursing.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply the code reaches the return mid; I checked that by altering the printf statement just above it
If you

Comment: @Prayansh Srivastava What does this code snippet if (mid == start)
    {
        if(element!=end) mean?!

Comment: @Prayansh Srivastava It seems that your function does not make any sense> There is n0 need to investigate it. You should rewrite it anew.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply
WeatherVane  the code reaches the return mid; I checked that by altering the printf statement just above it

@EOF : I returned BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, end); Is that what you meant? That sends it into an infinte loop

VladfromMoscow : I tried dry running the algorithm before coding it and realised that to prevent it from going into an infinte loop we would have to do this. Its ambiguous because in C it takes 3.5 as 3.

It might be worth mentioning that I am running C on Xcode

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Compile it, its giving the correct answer, just not returning it.

Comment: *"the code reaches the return mid"* yes but when it drops back to the previous incarnation of the function, *that* returns `0`, see my answer.

Comment: You've got more fundamental problems than that. You are calling `BinaryRecursivSearch` without doing anything with its returned-value. So you've pretty much missed the whole point in recursion.

Comment: @Prayansh Srivastava You are mistaken. Your program is simply wrong. Take any other array and your program will not give any reasonable result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns `0` because these statements

```
BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, mid);
...
BinaryRecursivSearch(element, mid, end);
```

should be

```
return BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, mid);
...
return BinaryRecursivSearch(element, mid, end);
```

because they don't return anything, the final statement is executed

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude! I'd never have guessed that

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any sense in your function. 
For example I entirely do not understand what this code snippet means

```
if (mid == start)
{
    if(element!=end)
    {
        printf("\nElement not found");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Take into account that the array can contain any values not only { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } as in your program. Thus this code snippet does not make any sense for the binary search method. Try an array with different values and your program will not work as expected.

Or in this code snippet

else if (element < arr[mid])
        BinaryRecursivSearch(element, start, mid);

else if (element > arr[mid])
        BinaryRecursivSearch(element, mid, end);

you do not use the value returned by function BinaryRecursivSearch.

I suggest to write the recursive function simpler

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binary_search( const int a[], int n, int value )
{
    int middle;

    if ( n == 0 ) return -1;

    middle = n / 2;

    if ( value < a[middle] )
    {
        return binary_search( a, middle, value );
    }
    else if ( a[middle] < value )
    {
        int index = binary_search( a + middle + 1, n - middle - 1, value );
        return index == -1 ? -1 : index + middle + 1;
    }

    return middle;
}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    for ( int i = -1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d has index %d\n", i, binary_search( a, N, i ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
-1 has index -1
0 has index 0
1 has index 1
2 has index 2
3 has index 3
4 has index 4
5 has index 5
6 has index 6
7 has index 7
8 has index 8
9 has index 9
10 has index -1
```